# WinAPI Control to display image

Tags: image, winapi, user-interface, controls

Is there a GUI control that displays an image in the Windows API? I have considered the STATIC class but it only works on bmp files, and I need png, bmp, jpg, etc to work with it. And I prefer not to draw the image manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ListView, and set the background image using LVM_SETBKIMAGE. Another option is to use GDI+ and draw it yourself manually, which is also pretty simple.

Comment: Can you control the Z position that the image would draw at with GDI?

Answer (score 0):

From Windows Vista the static control can display a bitmap, icon or metafile.
Check the STM_SETIMAGE window message and dont forget to set the correct window style. Of course Microsoft fucked it up again as you can see from the resource leak note - be carefull.